# Cancelling an ExtJS component's event

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid panel, ***"ParentGrid"*** that is used to populate another grid, ***"Childgrid"*** on the page.

The *ChildGrid* is populated via a listener on the *ParentGrid* selection-change event. By default when the page loads, the *ParentGrid's* first row is selected and the *ChildGrid* is populated as expected.

The *ChildGrid* has similar functionality (a handler on the row selection event creates a chart). *ChildGrid* has the property, `selType: 'checkboxmodel'` and on page load a default chart is populated and all the rows of the *ChildGrid* need to be selected (which I can do).

The problem however is that when all the rows in *ChildGrid (say 10)* are selected by default the function is called *10* times. **I don't want to call this function when the page loads the first time**. How can you cancel the `'select'` event in specific cases, ***i.e.*** when the grid loads for the first time?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Why don't you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make use of setters and any of the other function calls that trigger events internally you can [pause and resume](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-suspendEvents) *all* the events on an observable component whilst you do something, ***e.g.***

```js
// grid: Ext.grid.Panel (or anything else which implements Ext.util.Observable)
grid.suspendEvents(false);  // boolean false discards events which would 
                            // otherwise queue until resumed (below)
// do something...
grid.resumeEvents();
```